# IVT-related Topology question

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, sorgenfrey-line

Is $[a,b]$ in ${\mathbb{R}_L}$ connected in the subspace topology?

I am trying to see whether or not the IVT applies for $[a,b]$ in the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}_L$ instead of $[a,b]$ inherited from $\mathbb{R}_U$. My proof of the IVT relies on $[a,b]$ being connected in the subspace topology so this would be helpful.

Comment: If by $\Bbb R_L$ you mean the lower limit (or Sorgenfrey) topology on $\Bbb R$, the answer is *no*: for any $c\in(a,b)$ the sets $[a,c)$ and $[c,b]$ are disjoint relatively open subsets of $[a,b]$ whose union is $[a,b]$.

Comment: That's what I figured but I wanted to believe it wasn't true.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do you have a suggestion for how to prove the IVT is/isn't correct for $[a,b]_L$ to $\mathbb{R}_U$?

Comment: I’ve just written one up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a counterexample to the intermediate value theorem when $[a,b]$ has the Sorgenfrey (or lower limit) topology, fix a point $c\in(a,b)$, and define $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }a\le x<c\\
1,&\text{if }c\le x\le b\,.
\end{cases}$$

Because $[a,c)$ is both open and closed in $[a,b]$, $f$ is continuous, and $f$ assumes **no** value strictly between $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)=1$.